# I have a script to upload a video or audio to a php server but not working

Tags: php

This script I have works well for uploading images but does not work for videos and audios. I believe it as to do with my php.ini setting not allowing videos. I have tried to increase the memory of file that can be uploaded but it still not working. Please what do I do. cos I  have tried to different script that failed. my php code below

```
   $preacher = $_POST['preacher'];
   $title = $_POST['title'];
   $filecontent =  $_FILES['file'];


    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))

    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

    {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
    else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else
        {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
        "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
```

Comment: You will need to tell us *how* exactly this doesn't work. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Check that the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are big enough to upload audios and videos.

Comment: you should see an error message in `print_r($_FILES);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If photos are fine but videos aren't, it's a near certainty that it's either `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size` in your `php.ini` file being too small. Remember that in most situations you'll need to restart your web server (Apache, often) for the change to get picked up.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you want to limit file size to 20kb ?. I think this is what preventing you from uploading the files `&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)` . If you don't want to limit file size with 20kb, remove it or increase the limit and try. Thanks.